# How to run React/Node app under sub directory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes

I am new to React and Node
I have built an App and I want to run on a Linux server under one subdirectory.
Right now it's working on http://www.domainname.com:3000
All my files are under the subdirectory so it should be working on http://www.domainname.com/abc/ and without port number e.g:3000

Node version is: 10.19.0

Thanks

Comment: Its a Godaddy Server

Comment: If you want to map ports on to public folders you need to set up reverse proxy with your web server

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide to follow

In summary:

- Remote login via ssh to your Linux server
- Then install Nginx, npm (and Certbot if you want)

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install git
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

- Deploy from git

```
sudo su
cd /var/www
mkdir yourdomain.com
git clone YOUR_REPOSITORY_URL yourdomain.com
```

- Generate the build

```
cd /var/www/yourdomain.com
npm install --save
npm run-script build
```

- Finally, configure the virtual host

```
cd /var/nginx/sites-available
nano default
```

and add this to the end of the file, replacing with your domain name

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default         upgrade;
    ''              close;
}
server {

       server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

       location / {
        # Backend nodejs server
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection  $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Save the file, check the script and restart nginx

```
nginx -t
sysytemctl restart nginx
```

Then you should be good to go

Source: https://medium.com/@poudel.01anuj/deploying-reactjs-project-on-the-linux-server-with-ssl-certificate-https-aa14bf2737aa. Follow after step 4 if you need SSL as well

Comment: Its a Godaddy Server

Comment: @VickyJha run ```npm run build:prod``` then upload the contents of your public folder after